# MS Access Query - Display All Rows from Original Joined Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to write a query that displays ALL revenue centers for a month whether they have revenue or not. This seems like a simple request but I have seemed to hit a brick wall. Below is my SQL:

```
SELECT ID_ItemNominal, ItemNominal_Description, Sum(Nz([ITM_Net],0)) AS ITM_Net_Total
FROM TSub_ItmNominal LEFT JOIN (T_Invoice RIGHT JOIN T_LineItems ON T_Invoice.ITM_Reference = T_LineItems.ITM_Reference) ON TSub_ItmNominal.ID_ItemNominal = T_LineItems.ITM_Nominal
WHERE (((Year([ITM_Date]))=[report_year] Or (Year([ITM_Date])) Is Null) AND ((Month([ITM_Date]))=[report_month]))
GROUP BY TSub_ItmNominal.ID_ItemNominal, TSub_ItmNominal.ItemNominal_Description
HAVING (((TSub_ItmNominal.ID_ItemNominal) Like "4*"))
ORDER BY TSub_ItmNominal.ID_ItemNominal;
```

- ID_ItemNominal = the Integer code for the Revenue Center
- ItemNominal_Description = the description of the Revenue Center
- ITM_Net = the Currency amount for the Line Item on the Invoice, to be `SUM` for a month total
- ITM_ Date = the Date of the Invoice

My thought was to use the `LEFT JOIN` to say that I want to see ALL of the revenue centers, even if those records do not have any data for that month. What I get is the centers that **DO** have revenue for the year but **DO NOT** have revenue for the month are not shown / filtered out.

What the Current query provides:

```
40500 | Sales - Digital | $###.##
40700 | Sales - Misc    | $###.##
40800 | Sales - Mail    | $###.##
40900 | Sales - Clothing| $0.00
```

We have not done any revenue under `40900` this year so far so it shows as a result in the query. We have done revenue in `40600` this year but not for the month of April. The `40600` seems to be filtered out by the `WHERE` part of the query as well as any other revenue centers that we have revenue for the year but not the selected date.

*I would like to see these revenue centers included in the query but show as $0.00 for the month.*

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I feel like I am close but I just can't seem to get the correct results. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why the optional `T_Invoice` join? This seems redundant. For readability, always period-qualify `SELECT` columns to source of table in `JOIN` queries. E.g., `ItemNominal_Description` is unclear of its origination and likely not in the sub line items table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the original table with all rows and join your query to it like

```
SELECT t1.ID_ItemNominal, t1.ItemNominal_Description,t2.ITM_Net_Total
FROM TSub_ItmNominal AS t1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID_ItemNominal, ItemNominal_Description, Sum(Nz([ITM_Net],0)) AS ITM_Net_Total
FROM TSub_ItmNominal LEFT JOIN (T_Invoice RIGHT JOIN T_LineItems ON T_Invoice.ITM_Reference = T_LineItems.ITM_Reference) ON TSub_ItmNominal.ID_ItemNominal = T_LineItems.ITM_Nominal
WHERE (((Year([ITM_Date]))=[report_year] Or (Year([ITM_Date])) Is Null) AND ((Month([ITM_Date]))=[report_month]))
GROUP BY TSub_ItmNominal.ID_ItemNominal, TSub_ItmNominal.ItemNominal_Description
HAVING (((TSub_ItmNominal.ID_ItemNominal) Like "4*")) )  AS t2 ON t1.ID_ItemNominal = t2.ID_ItemNominal
WHERE ((([t1l].[ID_ItemNominal]) Like "4*"))
ORDER BY t1.ID_ItemNominal;
```

Comment: BEAUTIFUL, thank you! There was some tweaking to be done but very minimal. That you so much for the help. I think I will have to create some more of these in the future but you have given me a good foundation to launch off from. Thanks again!

Comment: @JamesCrafton - please mark as the answer or at least upvote it as helpful. Little things that matter

Comment: Good to go! I did upvote, just don't have the rep to have it actually count :(

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you run `LEFT JOIN` + `WHERE` you run an analogous `INNER JOIN`. But according to your specifications, the sub items table should be optionally joined since it can contain actual sales data not exhaustive of all revenue centers.

Therefore, run the `WHERE` filtering within a subquery and then have this subquery left joined to main set of revenue centers. Also, for readability below converts `RIGHT JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` and uses table aliases instead of full table names.

```sql
SELECT main.ITM_Nominal, 
       main.ItemNominal_Description, 
       SUM(NZ(sub.[ITM_Net], 0)) AS ITM_Net_Total

FROM (T_LineItems AS main 
LEFT JOIN T_Invoice AS inv 
   ON inv.ITM_Reference = main.ITM_Reference)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID_ItemNominal, [ITM_Net]
    FROM TSub_ItmNominal 
    WHERE ID_ItemNominal ALIKE '4%' 
      AND YEAR([ITM_Date]) = [report_year] 
      AND MONTH([ITM_Date]) = [report_month]
) AS sub
   ON sub.ID_ItemNominal = main.ITM_Nominal

GROUP BY main.ITM_Nominal, 
         main.ItemNominal_Description

ORDER BY main.ITM_Nominal;
```